# Double pipes in JavaScript (||) throw error instead of evaluate as falsy

Tags: javascript, undefined, boolean-operations

I read that the double pipes in JavaScript check to see if a variable is falsy, and that `undefined` is a falsy value in JavaScript, e.g.

> It means that if the value is falsey (e.g. 0, "", null, undefined (see
>   also All falsey values in JavaScript)), it will be treated as false;
>   otherwise it's treated as true.

So I tried this out and find that undefined indeed does not get evaluated as falsy but instead throws an error:

```
let elemContent = document.getElementById('content');

let a = null;
let b = 2;

elemContent.innerHTML += a || 'ok'; // "ok"
elemContent.innerHTML += b || 'ok'; // "2"
elemContent.innerHTML += whatever || 'ok'; // "ERROR: whatever is not defined"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ueqo6yko

**Is `undefined` a falsy value in JavaScript or not, or how does one understand this contradiction?**

Comment: Replace `whatever` with `window.whatever` or declare `whatever`.

Comment: why hasn't anyone pointed out that double pipes are actually "Or Else". What this statement means is: evaluate the first condition, if the first condition is not false return the value or-else evaluate the second condition and return its value. Like any condition it is dangerous because the valid value of 0 is evaluated as false so better hope that a or b will never be zero or the second condition will be evaluated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because in your code, `whatever` is not only `undefined` but furthermore **not declared**

To avoid this error, you could do the following:

```
let elemContent = document.getElementById('content');

let a = null;
let b = 2;

elemContent.innerHTML += a || 'ok'; // "ok"
elemContent.innerHTML += b || 'ok'; // "2"
elemContent.innerHTML += (typeof whatever !== 'undefined' && whatever) || 'ok3'; // "ok3"
```

Comment: Yup, `elemContent.innerHTML += undefined || 'ok'` will work.

Comment: @laruiss that one line of code could cause a LOT of confusion

Comment: Omg @laruiss are you trying to make OP pull his hair out?  :)  **never** call a variable `undefined` unless you want all other programmers ever to read your code to curse at you!  :)  And @Kokodoko, your example is a very complicated way of writing `elemContent.innerHTML += 'ok'`  :)

Comment: Hey @StijndeWitt and everybody! First, it was mostly for fun, and no, I do don't write that kind of crazy stuff :-D  But it was a reminder of one (out of many) wtf of this language... that I really like despite -or maybe because of?- them.

Comment: @StijndeWitt My example was to prove that `undefined` is falsy, that was the question of the OP :)

Comment: @laruiss Yeah I saw your code so I got you understand it yourself but the humor/wtf may go unnoticed for beginners  :)

Answer (score 13):

`undefined` is indeed falsy, but it's an error in JavaScript to use a variable before it's been declared.

Add a `let whatever = undefined` somewhere to see the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 8):

`undefined` and error with `not defined` are different. `undefined` is a value for **declared** variable, when error with `not defined` means, that your variable is not declared.

An example with `undefined`:

```js
let elemContent = document.getElementById('content');

let a = null;
let b = 2;
let whatever;

console.log(whatever)

elemContent.innerHTML += a || 'ok'; // "ok"
elemContent.innerHTML += b || 'ok'; // "2"
elemContent.innerHTML += whatever || 'ok'; // "whatever is undefined"
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

An example with `not defined` error:

```js
let elemContent = document.getElementById('content');

let a = null;
let b = 2;

elemContent.innerHTML += a || 'ok'; // "ok"
elemContent.innerHTML += b || 'ok'; // "2"
elemContent.innerHTML += whatever || 'ok'; // "ERROR: whatever is not defined"
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

And here is an example, how you can check, does variable declared and does it have a value (not `undefined`):

```js
let test = "test";

if (typeof test !== undefined) {
  console.log("'test' is declared");
  if(test) {
    console.log("'test' has a value (not 'null', 'false', 'undefined'...)");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To confirm that undefined is falsy:

```js
var whatever = undefined;
console.log(whatever || "undefined is really falsy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let elemContent = document.getElementById('content');

let a = null;
let b = 2;
let c;


elemContent.innerHTML += a || 'ok'; // "ok"
elemContent.innerHTML += b || 'ok'; // "2"
elemContent.innerHTML += c || 'ko'; // "ko"
elemContent.innerHTML += whatever || 'ok'; // "ERROR: whatever is not defined"
```

c is `undefined`. whatever is `undeclared`